How to fix inconsistent retrieval of data from MySql database?
So basically I have this android app and I use an API (requesting via Volley) to interact with a lambda function to use an RDS MySQL instance.
Flow :- make payload in the app -> send request -> lambda function executes the query in the payload.
Now, the main problem is that, after the query is executed successfully, I am able to see the changes in the database using MySQL workbench instantly, but the app still retrieves old data for approximately 20-30 min and after that it is able to fetch the updated data.
I am not able to find a way to avoid this and it is causing inconsistent behavior in the app.
I'm sorry if made a mistake in my description since I haven't asked much questions.
Here is an example of how I do it in the client side :
String message = String.format("Successfully participated in %s",mtitle );
String title = "A new step forward!";
String type = "simple";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AscendixPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String userEmail = sharedPreferences.getString("user_email","");

String query = String.format("INSERT INTO participants (player_id,tournament_id) VALUES ('%s',%s);UPDATE user_info SET balance = balance - %s WHERE email = '%s';UPDATE tournament SET current_pool = current_pool + %s WHERE tournamentid = %s;INSERT INTO notifications (inbox_id , message , title , type ) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s');",userEmail,matchid,entry,userEmail,entry,matchid,userEmail,message,title,type);

                    //todo : handle latency

                    try{

                        jsonObject.put("action","query");
                        jsonObject.put("query",query);

                    }catch (JSONException e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    tournamentHandler tournamentHandler = new tournamentHandler();
                    tournamentHandler.matchRequest(jsonObject, JoinMatchActivity.this, new tournamentHandler.DataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataReceived(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {

                            Toast.makeText(JoinMatchActivity.this, "Joined Match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            joinBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            resultBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            waitBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                            try {

                                notifyRequest notifyRequest = new notifyRequest();
                                notifyRequest.notifySingleUser(JoinMatchActivity.this, message, title, type, userEmail);

                            }catch (Exception e){

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String errorMessage) {

                        }
                    });

here is the lambda function code that is invoked:
import pymysql
import json
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT
from datetime import datetime, date, time,timedelta

#config values
endpoint = 'ascendixdb.ca5uz0m6irp9.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
user_name = 'admin'
password1 = 'gggwasdf162534'
db = 'ascendix_db'

class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date, time)):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, timedelta):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

#connection
connect = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=user_name, password=password1, database=db,client_flag = CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS)

def sql_handler(query):

    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print(query)

    if "select" in query.casefold():

        try:

            cursor.execute(query)
            data = (list(cursor.fetchall()))
            
            print(data)

            response_data = [list(item) for item in data]
            response = json.dumps({'body':{"data":response_data,"statusCode":200}},cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
            
            return response

        except Exception as e :
            
            response = {'body':{"data":[["Bad Request"]]}}
            print(e) 
            return json.dumps(response)
            

    else :
        
        try:
    
            cursor.execute(query) 
            connect.commit()
    
            response = {'body':{"data":[["Execution sucessful !"]],"statusCode":200}}
                
            return json.dumps(response)

        except Exception as e :
            
            response = {'body':{"data":[["Bad Request"]]}}
            print(e)
            return json.dumps(response)
            
            
def handler (event,context) :

    data = json.loads(event['body'])
    action = data['action']

    if action == "query":
        
        return sql_handler(data['query'])

